# EasyHook: Inject 64 bit dll from 32 bit app in native C app?

Tags: c, easyhook

Is it possible to inject 64 bit dll into 64 bit host app from 32 bit app in native c? (not C# or managed c++)

I compiled the dll I want to inject in both 32 and 64 form, but when I call

```
RhInjectLibrary(pid,0,EASYHOOK_INJECT_DEFAULT,path,path64,NULL);
```

I get WOW error.

32 into 32 injection works fine.

Comment: As far as I understand, it is not possible. You can inject 32 bit DLL into 32 bit process from 64 bit app, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a helper 64-bit application that does the injection for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot since x86 application cannot even OpenProcess of a x64 process.